# How to calculate $\int_{|z|=4} \frac{z^2dz}{e^{z^2}-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I have an integral $$\int_{|z|=4} \frac{z^2dz}{e^{z^2}-1}$$
I've tried to calculate it using the Residue theorem. So I've found the 9 poles, $z=0$ and $z_{mn}=\sqrt{2\pi n}e^{i\pi \frac{(1+2m)}{4}}$, where $m=0,1,2,3$ and $n=1,2$.
But I can't understand how to find the residue of the poles. It's simple poles and I need to calculate
$$\lim_{z\to z_{mn}} \frac{z^2(z-z_{mn})}{e^{z^2}-1}$$
How can I calculate it?

Comment: I got zero, both with residues and with contour integral

Comment: Eventually I got it too